# What do you call a naughty, mischievous little boy?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I've searched a bunch of dictionaries and forums, and here's what I found:

***Rascal*** is the best option, but I need more.

***Varlet*** is archaic, and I need some more context.

***Scamp*** is good, but isn't it too approving? Otherwise seems to be a match.

***Imp*** is fine, but I need more context. What are the nuances? When is it preferrable?

***Trickster*** or ***Prankster*** seems fine, but I can't say what's the difference between them.

I need to clarify these terms and find the most suitable one.

Example: *Thus they [trolls] eat children, considering them mischievous snotty **pranksters**.*

It's meant to be a little funny and not really angry, like when your grandma is going to give you some pies, despite you did a non-harmful trick.

Comment: rascal works best. Check the old TV show: The Little Rascals. trickster and prankster sound like adults or teenagers. If you are writing a book the phrase: "considering them" is very heavy.

Comment: If it's meant to be 'not angry', why do you think _scamp_ is 'too approving'? _Varlet_ is certainly archaic and doesn't mean a child. An _imp_ is a mischievous supernatural being, or by extension a mischievous child.

Comment: @Lambie Many thanks

Comment: A minor suggestion: The idiomatic way to say it is *"What do you call...?"* not "how can you call".